# Python Regex to extract response from a modem AT command

Tags: python, regex

When sending a command to a modem, one usually sends a command (e.g. `AT`), followed by a `\r`. One then listens to the modem to see the result of the command, where this command itself is repeated. So a typical communication feedback from the modem looks like

```
AT\r\rOK\r\n
```

In case of an error it looks like

```
AT\r\rERROR\r\n
```

but in general, depending on the actual AT command, the returned value could be anything aside from `OK` and `ERROR`.

I would like to extract this response, i.e. a regular expression that returns me the `OK`, the `ERROR` or whatever the modem replies. Here are the conditions:

- I want to verify the original command in the string, i.e. `ATX\r\rOK\r\n` should not match when the command was just `AT`.
- I do not care about how many whitespace characters are present at all, the only thing I expect is to have a `\n` at the end. So `AT\rOK\n` and `AT\nOK\r\r\n` should match as well, but not `AT\nOK\r\r`.
- Last, I do not care about extra stuff on the left side as long as they are separated from the AT command by whitespace characters. So `OK\rAT\rOK\n`  should match (i.e. the  right-side occurrence of `OK`), but `XAT\rOK\r\n` should not match.

Is it possible to do this with one single regex in order to extract the modem response, or do I need to make multiple regex searches? To see if the whole thing matches correctly at all, I might have found already an expression:

```
r = re.compile("\s+AT\s+\w+\s*\\n$")
```

But how to extract what the `\w+` consists of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `()` around the part you want to extract, so your regex reads `r"(?<!\S)AT\s+(\w+)\s*\n`. You then get one group together with the match, that you can extract e.g. with `group`:

```
r.search("yourText").group(1)
```

Comment: I guess that's it! But I realized the expression you have used in your answer is incorrect as it matches `"OK\rAAT\nOK\n"` (should not be the case as the part inside is `AAT`). Any suggestion to improve this? I tried `[^\s]` with and without a `*` and `+` but does not work either.

Comment: @Alex The regex `(?<!\S)AT\s+(\w+)\s*\n` should work now. I edited the answer

Comment: I found that `[^\s]` will not work since the character `^` means inversion. Therefore I tried `[\s^]` instead, but this also did not work. An expression like `AT\rOK\n` was not matched. Why?

Comment: @Alex `\S` is the same as `[^\s]` but the problem was that you have to put this character class of non-spaces inside the look around assertion which means that the regex should only find a result if AT is not preceded by a non-space.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind to suppress matches preceded by non-space characters, and parentheses to capture the response: `r"(?<!\S)AT\s+(\w+)\s*\n$"` (`\S` means any non-space character). Then, you can extract the response with `group(1)`, provided the result from `re.search` is not `None`.

```
>>> p = re.compile(r"(?<!\S)AT\s+(\w+)\s*\n$")
>>> p.search('ATX\r\rOK\r\n')
>>> p.search('AT\rOK\n')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10049df30>
>>> _.group(1)
'OK'
>>> p.search('AT\nOK\r\r\n')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10049df30>
>>> p.search('AT\nOK\r\r')
>>> p.search('OK\rAT\rOK\n')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1004a4198>
>>> p.search('XAT\rOK\n')
```